# Questions about technical setup at specific hosts?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question

Are these kinds of requests on-point?

I personally wouldn't be able to answer them, and my first instinct would be to refer them to the hoster's technical support, but maybe I'm not being accommodating enough.

[How can I create an SPF record on my 1and1.com hosted domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/859/how-can-i-create-an-spf-record-on-my-1and1-com-hosted-domain)

[Blogger and Google App hosting at naked domain using 1&1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/880/blogger-and-google-app-hosting-at-naked-domain-using-11)

Comment: Both links point to the same question ...

Comment: lol.  apparently I suck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, on point. It's a sticky issue of 2 services interacting in a strange way. And some like this likely will get a "contact the host support" type answer.

Comment: +1, but it is also conceivable that someone else may know exactly how to do what is asked without requesting help from the host's support team. My worry is, how soon would such answers become 'dated', and who is going to maintain them?

Comment: I am a web host, and my control panel changes very, very frequently as far as features and how to get to them while it evolves. An answer to how to manipulate MX records using my CP would be good for .. perhaps ~120 days.

Comment: Maybe you can get a "contact the host support - and tell them *this*" so we can clarify the issue they are having and make their support call more effective.

Comment: Tim Post, late reply here: I would prefer a well formatted and articulate out-of-date answer as a basis for solving my problem to the current dog's breakfast of terrible forums and mailing list posts. The fact that SE site questions have dates attached to activity on them makes them more useful -- I can see immediately that the answer may be out of date.